# how to return json data from ajax in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

how i return my json data in html page.i have this code in js file

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'auth.json',
  type: "GET",
  dataType : "jsonp",
 success: function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, v) {
        // For each record in the returned array
        $('#div_id').append(v.room_id); 
    });
```

and index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>AjaxCall</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="room_id">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i have json file. but i have not idea how i do this. pleas help me. thank u!

Comment: Do you get any error? Have any fiddle?

Comment: Try $('#room_id').append(v.room_id)

Comment: Why do you set the `dataType` to `jsonp` if you request a `json` formatted file? (At least it does not look like you really do a `jsonp` but a `json` request)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks incomplete. Also you should use the div ID "room_id" instead of the wrong "div_id".

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'path\auth.json',
   type: "GET",
   dataType : "json",
   success: function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, v) {
         $('#room_id').append(v.room_id); 
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: thank u but not this work.no error found.but i can't understand how i do this.pleas give me simple step for this.

Comment: Have you used the correct path of json file? Is it in local or in remote server?